# Mongodb: How to do a work like `groupby` of mysql?

Tags: php, mongodb

I am using MongoDB PHP Library to malipulate mongodb data.
docs: https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/master/tutorial/collation/#aggregation

How to do a work in mongodb like `groupby` of mysql?

for example,there is a collection:

```
    $collection=[
        ['id'=>'xxx','county'=>'Montgomery','state'=>'Alabama','abbr'=>'AL'],
        ['id'=>'xxx','county'=>'Calhoun','state'=>'Alabama','abbr'=>'AL'],
        ['id'=>'xxx','county'=>'Alameda','state'=>'California','abbr'=>'CA'],
        ['id'=>'xxx','county'=>'Butte','state'=>'California','abbr'=>'CA'],
        ['id'=>'xxx','county'=>'Baker','state'=>'Georgia','abbr'=>'GA'],
        ['id'=>'xxx','county'=>'Clarke','state'=>'Georgia','abbr'=>'GA'],
    ];
```

I want to get fields `state` and `abbr`,and save them into a new collection,the result is like this:

```
$newCollection=[
    ['id'=>'xxx','state'=>'Alabama','abbr'=>'AL'],
    ['id'=>'xxx','state'=>'California','abbr'=>'CA'],
    ['id'=>'xxx','state'=>'Georgia','abbr'=>'GA'],
];
```

How to do it?

Comment: what is the problem in this, do group by on state and abbr. Project only that group by element and then save in the collection using foreach.

Answer (score -1):

MongoDB equivalent of the group by statement is aggregation framework (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/). Though for your requirement, if you want a new collection, you will have to use mapReduce or MongoDB views.